# How to use the "return value" in writing mode

Tags: python-2.7, file, return

So I have this project which runs fine, the only problem is I the return value that I get to be written inside inside a file. Here's my code:

```
def write_substrings_to_file(s,filename):
if type(s) != str:
    raise TypeError ("You have entered something other than a sting, please enter a string next time!")
if s=="" or filename=="":
    raise ValueError
why=open(filename,"wt")
output=""
if len(s)==1:
    return s[0]
for i in range(0,len(s)):
    for n in range(0,len(s)):   
        output+=s[i:n+1]
    break
return output+write_substrings_to_file(s[1:],filename)
why.write()
why.close()
```

In other words I need the last three lines to be

```
return output+write_substrings_to_file(s[1:],filename)
why.write(return)
why.close()
```

yet I can't use return in such way, I get the following error

> TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'type' objects

Comment: Can you explain what the function is supposed to do?

Comment: Let us say the input is 'abc'
open a file, write the following:
a
ab
abc
b
bc
c
another explain, input: great
g
gr
gre
grea
great
r
re
rea
reat
e
ea
eat
a
at
t
and then save that file, another thing is has to be recursive function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish in your function so this might not be what you want, but your problem is you're trying to write out `return` which is a function, when I think you want to write the string you build up recursively instead and then return:

```
my_ret = output+write_substrings_to_file(s[1:],filename)
why.write(my_ret)
why.close()
return my_ret
```

Thanks for explaining the question, this is the code I would use:

```
def my_write(s, ind = 0, step = 1):
    ret = []

    if ind+step <= len(s):
        ret.append(s[ind:ind+step])
        step += 1
    else:
        step = 1
        ind += 1

    if ind < len(s):
        ret += my_write(s,ind,step)

    return ret

ret = my_write('abc')
print ret #<- outputs ['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'b', 'bc', 'c']
```

And for code golf:

```
def break_word(s):
    ret = [s[:x] for x in range(1,len(s)+1)]
    ret += break_word(s[1:]) if len(s) > 1 else []
    return ret

ret = break_word('abc')
print ret #<- outputs ['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'b', 'bc', 'c']
```